# Is there any restriction on what constitutes a veil for bedeken?

Tags: minhag, clothing, wedding

What can be considered a veil to be used in a [bedeken](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Badeken) at a wedding?

(See also my other [related question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/9487/734))

Comment: Paul, I've edited your question so that it doesn't appear to be a request for personal Halachic guidance, [which this site can't provide](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/312/perhaps-the-community-moderators-should-enact-a-more-strict-policy-regarding-hala), but your Rabbi can. In addition, I deleted your second question, since that [should](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/335/how-to-deal-with-multiple-questions-asked-in-one) be asked as a separate question. You can retrieve the text from the [revision history](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/revisions/9486/1).

Comment: Noted.  Thanks!  I will create and link the second question.

Answer (score 3):

*Nit'ei Gavri'el* on the topic [quotes](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46545&st=&pgnum=105) the *Shulchan Aruch* to say that the veil should be opaque from the outside and should not be ornamented with gold and silver thread. The reason for opacity seems to be to demonstrate that the marriage is unconditional on factors such as money because if the bride cannot see what the groom is holding as he approaches her she cannot possibly be making her decision to marry him on the basis of its value. The rather extensive footnotes point to but do not explicate the reasoning for the limitation on gold and silver thread.

In more extensive footnotes he also cites practices of several sources to make the veil out of a special preexisting object - cloth used to cover a *shofar*, material used in performance of some other *mitzva* or even a previously-owned piece of fabric that had belonged to a *tzadik*.

Answer (score 2):

Anything that covers the face is fine. There are those that use thick material which is not see through, and there are those that use material that is very sheer.

Comment: A source for your first sentence would be nice.

Comment: Can you be more specific about "face"?  Does that require lower than the eyes?  Lower than the chin?  Lower than the neck?