# What happens at bedeken?

Tags: minhag, clothing, wedding

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Badeken) says both that the groom puts on the veil, and in a separate paragraph says he uncovers it.  Which is it?

Does he put it on, lift it, and then drop it again?

Can he just lift it and then drop it, but not put it on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think customs vary from place to place.
At my wedding, and at least 3 others that I have been too, the veil was already inserted into the bride's hair by the hair and makeup person, but flipped back so that it does not cover the face.  At the Bedeken, the Groom then pulled the veil from 'bandana status' to 'cover the face status'

Answer (score 4):

Usually the groom puts on the veil and it stays on until the conclusion of the Chupa. There are some Chasidim where the father of the bride puts on the veil. Then right before the Brachos of the Chupa they lift the veil and the Chassan confirms that this is the Kalla.

Comment: "[T]hey" being...?