# Source of Wedding Veil

Tags: marriage, clothing, wedding

So I know it is customary that brides wear veils during the wedding, and the custom of the bedeken comes from the story of Rachel and Lea, but where does the custom of wearing the veil itself come from?

From tanach it is described as if wearing a veil was something that brides in the Canaan area just seemed to do. I know that it often happens in Judaism where local customs that mesh well are picked up and new meaning is added to such customs (ex upsherin). Is this the case here with a brides veil? If so, does anyone know what this local interpretation of the veil was?

Conversely, does the veil have any halachic ramifications or is it more just a symbolic customary thing?

Thanks!

Comment: http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/267679/jewish/Why-Does-a-Bride-Wear-a-Veil.htm Re: Halachic ramifications, a thick veil has the advantage of the bride not seeing the ring, thus not being "fooled" about its value  (which would invalidate the kiddushin).

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/9486/is-there-any-restriction-on-what-constitutes-a-veil-for-bedeken

Comment: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/2749/kallahs-veil-under-chupah